# RAT in Kali linux

Tags: attacks

I have created an android RAT using metasploit's meterpreter reverse_tcp payload. And I can control my phone remotely.But the communication is very slow.When I remotely scan the camera it is very slow.Is there any other ways to build a faster communicating android RAT?

Comment: "How can I build a faster RAT?" is a pure programming question and is really, really broad. There are also a lot of variables to consider.